# capturing text from text editors

Tags: .net

i researched on the internet but i couldnt find . how sqlassistant like programs can capture text from another text editors (notepad++ , sql management studio etc.)

for example , if u press ctrl + mouse left click in notepad++ , sql assistant detect text and repaint it blue and open stored procedure clicked in its own window.

is it possible with Hook api's ? i downloaded many api's examples written in c# , but no example about capturing text , is it possible with managed code ?

Answer (score 1):

Programs like that use regular Win32 API calls to inspect window contexts. They use global keyboard hooks to detect the keypresses, then use calls like GetActiveWindow to determine what kind of window/control is selected and how to interact with it.

[Here's an example for setting a global hook in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Win32 API function to get an object / object' content
some win32 api function like getwindow-getwindowex-findwindow-findwindowex and so on from user32.dll can be usefull
in [www.daneshjooyar.com](http://www.daneshjooyar.com) there is some video about using api function in c#